# Give variable name based on user login id

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to crate a static list of class's object and wnat to give its name as per UserLogin ID.

I have tried following code but its not working.

```
 public static class Usersetting
{
    public static int nUserId=0;
}

public static class SetFormat
{
    public static List<ConditionalFormat> Usersetting.nUserId = new List<ConditionalFormat>();
}
```

In Usersetting.nUserId , I set userlogin id and I want to declare static List whcih name will be userlogin id.

Is this thing possible? If yes then How to achieve this?

Thanks,
Hitesh

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Dictionary<int, ConditionalFormat>`:

```
public static class SetFormat
{
    public static Dictionary<int, ConditionalFormat> Usersetting = new Dictionary<int, ConditionalFormat>();
}
```

and then use like this:

```
SetFormat.Usersetting[Usersetting.nUserId]
```